# Excluding a SQL File Group from DPM Backup

Tags: sql-server, scdpm

I have numerous SQL 2012 databases that are being backed up by Microsoft's Data Protection manager (DPM) 2012.  However, in each of these databases there is a specific file group that contains a large amount of non-critical (easily recreateable) data that is changes often and causes our backup size to grow exponentially.  I don't want the data in this file group backed up.

I want to find out how I can (either through DPM or a setting in SQL Server) instruct DPM to exclude a specific file group from the backup.  I want to do this using the native SQL VSS backup and I like (and really need) the auto-protect feature of DPM to backup new databases, so individually selecting SQL data files for the backup isn't really an option.  Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

*Disclaimer, I posted this question on MS TechNet, but have received no response there.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your exact requirements are possible. The only way I know you could achieve something similar would be to exclude certain files from a protection group. I know this isn't the way to go for your specific needs but it's the only way I can think to do it.